# why is android studio red bulb not showing unless forced?

Tags: android-studio

The bulb used to show on an unresolved reference or if I had an interface to implement...handy.  now I have to force it.  Has any one seen this before? it seems to be happening in more than one project.

Answer (score 1):

You can call intention actions by pressing *Alt+Enter* at highlighted element. Please tell if it solves the issue for you?

Comment: Thats what is meant by unless forced in the question

Comment: Looks like usability problem. Here is the issue created for it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209674. Please follow